# Upgrade Plesk server to PHP 5.3.x

Tags: php, rpm

I have a Virtuozzo VPS running Plesk 8.x on CentOS 4.4 and I'd like to install that latest PHP 5.3 release on it. Ideally I'd like to run 4 and 5 side by side, but I'll settle for only running 5 if I have to.

*(Note that Plesk runs two instances of Apache/PHP -- one for the control panel and another to serve the client sites -- and I'm looking to upgrade the client instance, not the control panel instance)*

I've downloaded the required RPMs from http://www6.atomicorp.com/channels/atomic/centos/4/i386/RPMS/, but when I try to install them I get this error:

```
[root@hq phprpm]# rpm -i *.rpm
warning: php-5.3.6-3.el4.art.i386.rpm: V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID 5ebd2744
        file /etc/php.ini from install of php-common-5.3.6-3.el4.art conflicts with file from package php-4.3.9-3.18.1.swsoft
        file /usr/bin/php from install of php-cli-5.3.6-3.el4.art conflicts with file from package php-4.3.9-3.18.1.swsoft
        file /usr/bin/phpize from install of php-cli-5.3.6-3.el4.art conflicts with file from package php-devel-4.3.9-3.18.1.swsoft
        file /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf from install of php-5.3.6-3.el4.art conflicts with file from package php-4.3.9-3.18.1.swsoft
        file /var/www/icons/php.gif from install of php-5.3.6-3.el4.art conflicts with file from package php-4.3.9-3.18.1.swsoft
```

How can I install the PHP5 files at a separate location from the PHP4 ones? What kind of settings will I need to tweak because it's not in the default location?

If I try to upgrade PHP4 instead of installing PHP5 alongside it, I get this error:

```
[root@hq phprpm]# rpm -Uvh php-*.rpm
warning: php-5.3.6-3.el4.art.i386.rpm: V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID 5ebd2744
error: Failed dependencies:
        php = 4.3.9-3.18.1.swsoft is needed by (installed) php-domxml-4.3.9-3.18.1.swsoft.i386
        php = 4.3.9-3.18.1.swsoft is needed by (installed) php-gd-4.3.9-3.18.1.swsoft.i386
        php = 4.3.9-3.18.1.swsoft is needed by (installed) php-imap-4.3.9-3.18.1.swsoft.i386
        php = 4.3.9-3.18.1.swsoft is needed by (installed) php-mbstring-4.3.9-3.18.1.swsoft.i386
        php = 4.3.9-3.18.1.swsoft is needed by (installed) php-mysql-4.3.9-3.18.1.swsoft.i386
        php = 4.3.9-3.18.1.swsoft is needed by (installed) php-pear-4.3.9-3.18.1.swsoft.i386
        php = 4.3.9-3.18.1.swsoft is needed by (installed) php-devel-4.3.9-3.18.1.swsoft.i386
        php = 4.3.9-3.18.1.swsoft is needed by (installed) php-ldap-4.3.9-3.18.1.swsoft.i386
        php = 4.3.9-3.18.1.swsoft is needed by (installed) php-odbc-4.3.9-3.18.1.swsoft.i386
        php = 4.3.9-3.18.1.swsoft is needed by (installed) php-pgsql-4.3.9-3.18.1.swsoft.i386
        php = 4.3.9-3.18.1.swsoft is needed by (installed) php-snmp-4.3.9-3.18.1.swsoft.i386
        php = 4.3.9-3.18.1.swsoft is needed by (installed) php-xmlrpc-4.3.9-3.18.1.swsoft.i386
```

It's failing because Plesk rolls their own version of PHP. I tried to workaround that with RPM --nodeps, but got this error:

```
[root@hq phprpm]# rpm -Uvh php*.rpm --nodeps
warning: php-5.3.6-3.el4.art.i386.rpm: V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID 5ebd2744
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
        file /usr/bin/phpize from install of php-cli-5.3.6-3.el4.art conflicts with file from package php-devel-4.3.9-3.18.1.swsoft
```

If I try to uninstall php4 so I can install 5, I get this error:

```
[root@hq phprpm]# rpm -e --test php-4.3.9-3.18.1.swsoft php-gd-4.3.9-3.18.1.swsoft php-mbstring-4.3.9-3.18.1.swsoft php-devel-4.3.9-3.18.1.swsoft php-ncurses-4.3.9-3.18.1.swsoft php-pgsql-4.3.9-3.18.1.swsoft php-xmlrpc-4.3.9-3.18.1.swsoft php-domxml-4.3.9-3.18.1.swsoft php-imap-4.3.9-3.18.1.swsoft php-mysql-4.3.9-3.18.1.swsoft php-pear-4.3.9-3.18.1.swsoft php-ldap-4.3.9-3.18.1.swsoft php-odbc-4.3.9-3.18.1.swsoft php-snmp-4.3.9-3.18.1.swsoft
error: Failed dependencies:
        php is needed by (installed) psa-prevztune-8.1.0-17.swsoft.81563.noarch
        php >= 4.2 is needed by (installed) ZendOptimizer-3.0.1-1.swsoft.i386
        php is needed by (installed) psa-php4-configurator-1.4.0-cos4.build86080722.02.noarch
        /usr/bin/php is needed by (installed) psa-horde-3.1.7-cos4.build86080722.02.noarch
        php-gd is needed by (installed) psa-php4-configurator-1.4.0-cos4.build86080722.02.noarch
        php-mbstring is needed by (installed) psa-php4-configurator-1.4.0-cos4.build86080722.02.noarch
        php-domxml is needed by (installed) psa-php4-configurator-1.4.0-cos4.build86080722.02.noarch
        php-imap is needed by (installed) psa-php4-configurator-1.4.0-cos4.build86080722.02.noarch
        php-mysql is needed by (installed) psa-php4-configurator-1.4.0-cos4.build86080722.02.noarch
```

Please keep in mind that Virtuozzo VPS's don't have yum installed by default -- and I've heard it's a pain in the ass to get it working -- so I'd like to do everything via RPM.

I've checked the related questions on Server Fault, but they didn't address this specific error, and I didn't find anything on Google that was helpful.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just removing the old PHP packages with rpm -e --nodeps, and then installing the new ones with rpm -ivh --nodeps, and that worked.

Comment: That ended up break Plesk, though, so now I'm trying to find a solution to that -- http://serverfault.com/questions/273361/plesk-broken-after-mysql-upgrade

Answer (score -1):

Just install it through yum. "yum search php" their should be a php5 option or install a repo that has it.

Comment: That'd work for a regular CentOS installation, but Virtuozzo/Plesk introduces some complexities.