# Plesk broken after MySQL upgrade

Tags: mysql

I have a Virtuozzo VPS on a CentOS 4.4 box running Plesk 8.6. I upgraded MySQL from 4.1 to 5.0, but I had to use rpm -Uvh --nodeps to get around some Plesk packages that were dependent on mysqlclient14 specifically. I assumed they'd work fine once 15 was installed, because [Parallels claims that there aren't any compatibility problems upgrading MySQL](http://kb.parallels.com/1792). The upgrade works and it looks like the MySQL is running fine, but now Plesk gives this error at the login screen:

```
ERROR: PleskFatalException  
Components::componentUpdate() failed: Unable to exec utility packagemng: Empty error message from utility.
0: /usr/local/psa/admin/auto_prepend/auth.php3:530
```

Here's the error log from Plesk's instance of Apache:

```
[root@hq 5.0-centosplus]# tail -n 20 /usr/local/psa/admin/logs/httpsd_error_log
...
[Tue May 24 15:41:07 2011] [error] Components::componentUpdate() failed: Unable to exec utility packagemng: Empty error message from utility.
/usr/local/psa/admin/bin/packagemng: error while loading shared libraries: libmysqlclient.so.14: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

/usr/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.14 was replaced with libmysqlclient.so.15. How can I tell Apache/PHP it to use 15 instead of 14? I didn't see anything in httpsd.conf or php.ini.

I created symlink from the old 14 files in /usr/lib/mysql, but that didn't fix it. Now httpsd_error_log just says,

```
[Tue May 24 16:07:11 2011] [error] Components::componentUpdate() failed: Unable to exec utility packagemng: Empty error message from utility.
/usr/local/psa/admin/bin/packagemng: /usr/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.14: version `libmysqlclient_14' not found (required by /usr/local/psa/admin/bin/packagemng)
```

Comment: From my knowledge, PLESK 8.6 isn't compatible with MySQL 5. I had some similar issues on one of my boxes and ended up having to update Plesk to 9.5.x to get around the problem, the alternative was rolling back to MySQL 4 (That was the advice given to me by Parallels)

Comment: If you check out the link I posted above, the first line says, "Plesk Control Panel fully supports MySQL 5 since Plesk 8.1 version."

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by copying `libmysqlclient.so.14.0.0` and `libmysqlclient_r.so.14.0.0` from another 8.6 box, chmod'ing them 755, and creating symlinks from `libmysqlclient.so.14` and `libmysqlclient_r.so.14`, respectively. I also ran *ldconfig* afterwords, but I'm not sure if that's necessary or not.

Answer (score 0):

Install Atomic Rocket Turtle's RPM repository and type yum install mysqlclient14 mysqllibclient14. If it does not exist then:

- yum install mysql
- yum search mysql | grep client
- yum provides mysqllibclient.so.14
- yum install mysqlclient
- yum install mysql-libs

You should be able to successfully run Plesk 8.6 with MySQL-5 by he way, I did it and it worked fine! I would recommend to remove ART's repository afterwards, no need to want to run the newest rpm's all the time, causes more issues than pleasure.

I had the same issue as you, but with mysqllibclient.so.15. If you need help, look me up in #plesk on irc.freenode.net.

Comment: I can't downgrade to .14 because the MySQL5 packages depend on .15. Also, Virtuozzo VPSs don't have yum, so I need to do everything with RPM.